# Is there an alternative for psutil that works for windows

Tags: python, wmi, psutil

By this, I mean the fan speed and temperatures module do not work - I was wondering if there was an alternative that did the same job. I'm just making a simple program that prints out the speeds and names of fans, and temperatures of a PC.

I also tried WMI with this code - but it simply returned nothing:

```
import wmi

def display_temperature_info():
    c = wmi.WMI()

    temperatures = c.Win32_TemperatureProbe()
    if temperatures:
        print("Temperature Information:")
        for temp in temperatures:
            print(f"{temp.DeviceID}:")
            print(f"  Name: {temp.Name}")
            print(f"  Current Temperature: {temp.CurrentReading}°C")
            print()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_temperature_info()
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your current attempt? What does it output? Are there any errors?

Comment: maybe first check `print( temperatures )`